How to get a breakdown of how memory is being using on iPhone / mobile Safari?
First of all, using Safari on my MacBook (or even Safari Technology Preview), it is very hard to actually record a "Timeline" and have the memory info show up. 9/10 times the memory is not recorded for some reason, and only 1/10 times do I get a screen like this with some useful basic info:

ChatGPT says iPhone is only allocated probably between 700MB-1.5GB for the Safari app (can I check somehow?), and I've seen a couple times the memory chart on Safari laptop (viewing the debugger for what I'm browsing on my iPhone), show 1.1GB or slightly more for memory usage (I am trying to debug why my website is crashing only on iPhone Safari, but not laptop Chrome).
How can I get more detailed breakdowns of the memory usage on my website? Again, my iPhone 13 (iOS 17 something), is plugged into my MacBook, and I'm viewing my production website on mywebsite.com, viewing the elements panel works (HTML), and taking a timeline snapshot like in the image above, of what's happening on my mobile phone.
The memory info charts on Safari's debugger shows me only JavaScript Usage and Page Usage, but nothing else. Can't I see what objects are allocating the most memory or something? The "JavaScript Allocations" section of the debugger is always empty. And again, the memory portion of the chart only shows up like 1/10 refreshes/restarts of Safari on my MacBook :/
Any help at getting more insights into what's happening on the iPhone web for my app will be greatly appreciated. So far have spent all day to get very little information.
1/10 times I also get this screen, where there is a thin sliver of memory info, but then the page crashes, auto refreshes, and the timeline continues, not recording any memory info, but does record the network requests. Strange...

